# C++ algorithm to send email using Outlook

Tags: c++, outlook

I'm trying to send an email from my outlook account, which is already opened and logged, from a C++ algorithm, but really have no clue where to start (for the outlook-c++ integration), and google doesn't help me that much. Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Read about [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424.aspx).

Comment: Alternately, if you just need the program to send an email, you can use SMTP and route it through your exchange server. No Outlook integration needed.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Outlook Object Model. Outlook is just a regular IDispatch-friendly COM library. Use #import to import the type library and generate the headers, instantiate and use OOM objects, etc.

You might want to start at http://www.outlookcode.com/